# Operation timed out. Spring batch

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, hikaricp

I faced with problem on my local machine (When start in on server it is ok).

My config

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.hikari.validation-timeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.minimumIdle=50
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=1800000
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=120000
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=300000
spring.task.execution.pool.keep-alive=1800000
spring.datasource.hikari.poolName=SpringBootJPAHikariCP
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=120000
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=300000
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect
```

I tried different settings for connection pool. I thought this error related using another datasource for JobRepository, but he use is the same datasource. I tried annotation @Transactional

All logs

```
2021-02-27 15:56:24.106  WARN 68813 --- [ spring_batch56] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection   : SpringBootJPAHikariCP - Connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@5de66d55 marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08006), ErrorCode(0)

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:350) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:473) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:393) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:164) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:130) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-4.0.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3153) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3759) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:84) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:330) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:721) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:707) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Operation timed out
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:127) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:325) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:268) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:263) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1667) ~[na:na]
    Suppressed: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implWrite(NioSocketImpl.java:420) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.write(NioSocketImpl.java:440) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$2.write(NioSocketImpl.java:826) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketOutputStream.write(Socket.java:1052) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Operation timed out
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:325) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:982) ~[na:na]


2021-02-27 15:56:24.113  WARN 68813 --- [ spring_batch56] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08006
2021-02-27 15:56:24.113 ERROR 68813 --- [ spring_batch56] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
DB error: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute statement
2021-02-27 15:56:24.515  WARN 68813 --- [ spring_batch56] o.s.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory    : Error while extracting database name - falling back to empty error codes

org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:331) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:356) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory.getErrorCodes(SQLErrorCodesFactory.java:214) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.setDataSource(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:136) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.<init>(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:99) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcAccessor.getExceptionTranslator(JdbcAccessor.java:122) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1442) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:632) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:861) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:916) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao.persistSerializedContext(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:236) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao.updateExecutionContext(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:163) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.updateExecutionContext(SimpleJobRepository.java:210) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection$ClosedConnection.lambda$getClosedConnection$0(ProxyConnection.java:515) ~[HikariCP-4.0.2.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.getMetaData(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.getMetaData(ProxyConnection.java:380) ~[HikariCP-4.0.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.getMetaData(HikariProxyConnection.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:320) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 40 common frames omitted


2021-02-27 15:56:24.519 ERROR 68813 --- [ spring_batch56] o.s.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep  : JobRepository failure forcing rollback

org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [UPDATE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT SET SHORT_CONTEXT = ?, SERIALIZED_CONTEXT = ? WHERE STEP_EXECUTION_ID = ?]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Connection is closed; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:89) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1442) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:632) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:861) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:916) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao.persistSerializedContext(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:236) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao.updateExecutionContext(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:163) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.updateExecutionContext(SimpleJobRepository.java:210) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection$ClosedConnection.lambda$getClosedConnection$0(ProxyConnection.java:515) ~[HikariCP-4.0.2.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.prepareStatement(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:337) ~[HikariCP-4.0.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$SimplePreparedStatementCreator.createPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1555) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:614) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]

2021-02-27 15:56:24.529  INFO 68813 --- [ spring_batch56] o.s.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep  : Commit failed while step execution data was already updated. Reverting to old version.
2021-02-27 15:56:24.530 ERROR 68813 --- [ spring_batch56] o.s.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep  : Rolling back with transaction in unknown state
2021-02-27 15:56:24.531 ERROR 68813 --- [ spring_batch56] o.s.t.support.TransactionTemplate        : Application exception overridden by rollback exception

org.springframework.batch.core.step.FatalStepExecutionException: JobRepository failure forcing rollback
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:464) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate$ExecutingRunnable.run(TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate.java:262) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [UPDATE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT SET SHORT_CONTEXT = ?, SERIALIZED_CONTEXT = ? WHERE STEP_EXECUTION_ID = ?]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Connection is closed; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:89) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1442) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:632) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:861) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:916) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao.persistSerializedContext(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:236) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao.updateExecutionContext(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:163) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.updateExecutionContext(SimpleJobRepository.java:210) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection$ClosedConnection.lambda$getClosedConnection$0(ProxyConnection.java:515) ~[HikariCP-4.0.2.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.prepareStatement(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:337) ~[HikariCP-4.0.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$SimplePreparedStatementCreator.createPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1555) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:614) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]


    2021-02-27 15:56:46.311  WARN 68813 --- [ spring_batch57] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection   : SpringBootJPAHikariCP - Connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@576cf81a marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08006), ErrorCode(0)
    
    org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:350) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:473) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:393) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:164) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:130) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-4.0.2.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.2.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
        at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
        at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3153) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3759) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:84) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:330) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:721) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:707) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor71.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:308) ~[spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy107.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:489) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.saveAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:521) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor78.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:359) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:644) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Operation timed out
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:127) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:325) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:268) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:263) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1667) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:1049) ~[na:na]
        at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.readMore(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:161) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
        at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:128) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
        at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:113) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
        at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.read(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:73) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveChar(PGStream.java:441) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2057) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:323) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Operation timed out
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:325) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:982) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:469) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:463) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:70) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1421) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:1033) ~[na:na]


2021-02-27 15:57:49.892 ERROR 68813 --- [nio-8513-exec-2] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Encountered an error saving batch meta data for step step8 in job UserJob. This job is now in an unknown state and should not be restarted.

org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not roll back JPA transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Unable to rollback against JDBC Connection
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doRollback(JpaTransactionManager.java:563) ~[spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:838) ~[spring-tx-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:812) ~[spring-tx-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.completeTransactionAfterThrowing(TransactionAspectSupport.java:551) ~[spring-tx-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:298) ~[spring-tx-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy101.updateExecutionContext(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor73.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
```

What should be done for JobRepository?

Comment: Please put more log for review, if an error occurs in the business could be the cause of the total closure of the database connection.

Comment: how does your JDBC url look like?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres

Comment: But then I don't understand why you get SSLException because you are not using SSL

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Sorry I don't know

Comment: I am also getting the same error, is there any solution for it ?

Comment: Is there a solution for this?